# Обратная сторона "снисходительности"

Tags: обсуждение, предложение, локализация, индикатор-новичка

Сегодня обратил внимание на подсказку под вопросом от нового участника (шаблонную):

> XXX — новый участник сайта. Будьте снисходительны, задавая уточняющие вопросы, комментируя и отвечая. Почитайте про нормы поведения.

Глаз царапнуло "будьте снисходительны", решил на всякий случай посмотреть точное толкование. Гугл выдаёт:

> СНИСХОДИ́ТЕЛЬНЫЙ
>   1.
>   Не строгий, не взыскательный.
>   "Снисходительно нареч. отнестись к кому-н."
>   2.
>   Обидно-высокомерный.
>   "С. тон"

Очевидно, имелось ввиду первое, хорошо. Но проблема в том, что второе толкование не менее распространено, имеет смыл в данном контексте и является строгой противоположностью того, к чему мы стремимся!

Поэтому предлагаю либо просто убрать эту часть фразы про снисходительность, либо (в идеале) найти ей достойную замену. Предложения пишите в ответах.

Comment: словарь синонимов: «благожелательны, благосклонны, доброжелательны, дружелюбны, дружественны». или наоборот: «не будьте (слишком) строги/взыскательны/требовательны/придирчивы»

Comment: "Будьте дружелюбны", лучше звучит и не двусмысленно

Comment: "Окружите заботой и вниманием, не задавайте уточняющие вопросы, просто отвечайте." - как-то так. А серьёзно - в контексте "будте снисходительны, делая ч.л. в напавлении другого лица" = "не высокомерны", по моему мнению, со вторым вариантом никаких ассоциаций.

Comment: ни разу не видел этот текст

Comment: @avp Так выложите ответом, мне вполне нравится.

Comment: @Grundy как выяснилось, это текст, который появляется при наведении на плашку «нового участника».

Comment: В оригинале: «<username> is a new contributor to this site. Take care in asking for clarification, commenting, and answering. Check out our Code of Conduct.»

Comment: @Grundy вы просто не отвечаете на вопросы новичков))

Comment: @DaemonHK, отвечаю, просто я ни разу не наводил мышкой на подпись "Новый участник" :)

Comment: Дружелюбно удалять не понравившиеся вам ответы.

Comment: небось и мышки нет у @Grundy, или есть, но без курсора

Comment: @Eugene, в данном вопросе нет ни одного удаленного ответа

Answer (score 28):

Предложение @L.F.C.: заменить на "Будьте дружелюбны"

> Будьте дружелюбны, задавая уточняющие вопросы, комментируя и отвечая.

Comment: Будьте дружелюбны = be nice. Это же уже устарело.

Comment: @АндрейNOP , когда это бинайс успел устареть?)

Comment: @Andrio, со времён введения CoC

Comment: @АндрейNOP CoC это такой же be-nice, только с более конкретными формулировками.

Answer (score 19):

Мне была бы обидна сама плашка, почти независимо от текста на ней. Никогда не хотел особого отношения и воспринимал таковое как дискриминацию.

Comment: Согласен полностью, но увы — это решение сверху и подлежит лишь приемлемой адаптации.

Comment: @val: Года полтора назад у нас декларировалось самоуправление

Comment: @VladD не ... просто некоторые думали, что это действительно так.

Answer (score 15):

Второе трактование неочевидно или несущественно. Можно оставить имеющийся вариант.

Answer (score 9):

На мой взгляд лучше подходит:

> Будьте вежливы

, т.к. дружелюбие подразумевает стремление к дружбе, а задавать уточняющие вопросы, писать комментарии и давать ответы можно просто вежливо, т.е. без попыток проникновения в труднодоступные места без смазывающих материалов.

Comment: А разве ты не должен быть вежливым со всеми? Логическая ошибка * кродеца *.

Answer (score 8):

`Имейте это в виду, задавая уточняющие вопросы, комментируя и отвечая.`

Более общая фраза, подразумевающая не только лексическую корректность (но, например, готовность помочь задать хороший вопрос и не задать плохой, разъяснить механику сайта); апелляция к здравому смыслу, а не эмоциям.

На мой взгляд, суть не выходит за рамки написанного в ссылке из всплывающего предупреждения, формулировка нейтральна.

Answer (score 4):

Один из вариантов, [предложенных Баракиным](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/8934/%d0%9e%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d1%81%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d1%81%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%81%d1%85%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8#comment36779_8934):

> Будьте благосклонны, задавая уточняющие вопросы, комментируя и отвечая.

Обращаю внимание именно на этот вариант, потому что «будьте вежливы» — это слишком обобщённо, а потому не цепляет и ни к чему морально не обязывает.

К тому же, как по мне, быть благосклонным, то есть относиться с пониманием и участием, психологически проще. Просто же дружелюбие будет натянуто-наигранным, *особенно когда вопрошающий совсем начинающий в программировании или сам того не зная грубо нарушает неписаные правила*, и заряда позитива на такого участника просто не хватает. А вот с благосклонностью приходит не только дружелюбие, но и напоминание себе о том, кто такой вопрошающий, и желание помочь ему разобраться.

Answer (score 2):

А оригинал на английском как звучит? Разве Be condescending?

> %% is a new contributor to this site. Take care in asking for clarification, commenting, and answering.
> Check out our <Code of Conduct

ИМХО вопрос просто поправки перевода.

Answer (score 0):

Как насчет:

> XXX — новый участник сайта. Не грубите, задавайте уточняющие вопросы,
>   комментируйте и отвечайте. Почитайте про нормы поведения.

Comment: "комментируйте и отвечайте" — исходный посыл был о том, что не надо грубить в процессе, а комментировать и отвечать это само собой разумеется.

Answer (score -3):

`будьте терпимы` или `проявите больше терпимости`
 -- может что-то в таком духе?

Comment: Обидно-высокомерно терпеть всех этих ньюфагов, ага)

Comment: терпимость - это синоним буржуйского слова 'толерантность' :) и применяется обычно к людям с неадекватным поведением на почве медицинских расстройств :) или же к нац. меньшинствам в том или ином регионе где они практикуют собственные традиции и отстаивают собственные мировоззрения :)

Comment: А вот минусы то @avp за что? за предложение? если вам оно не нравиться по формулировке, это совершенно не означает что оно не достойно к рассмотрению. Невольно рисуется портрет минусующего как маленького, сопливого злово гоблина, имеющего свою точку зрения на все процессы во вселенной :)

Comment: @NewView Минус на мете — зачастую не показатель низкого качества ответа. Он никак не влияет на репутацию (как если на хабре минус к посту но не в карму) — просто голоса тут работают как выражение мнения сообщества по конкретному предложению. "если вам оно не нравиться по формулировке, это совершенно не означает что оно не достойно к рассмотрению" — голосование и выполняет функцию "рассмотрения".

Comment: @val, спасибо за разъяснение, но это не изменяет "массовый портрет" минусующих :)